# Bag #3, no instructions, no box

Tags: set-identification

I bought a box of LEGO bricks at a flea market. This bag came in it and we want to figure out what it is. The polybag says "3" and the number on it is 135149 but that’s all I have. [image]

Comment: Hi Emilee and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please don't add "thank you" as a comment, instead click the checkmark icon by the answer to indicate you are satisfied with it. Also see the [help] and [tour] pages to learn more about the site and our community!

Answer (score 13):

I think that is [7937](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7937-1#T=P) "Train Station"

Method:

1. I recognised the white girder piece as being in the [Saturn V](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=21309-1) set
2. Bricklink then shows [all other sets with that piece](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=64448&in=S)
3. Of the eight sets that have that piece in white, the 7937 also has two blue chairs and some grey ladders.